# Android Intent and Object (instance) of this new Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a problem of understanding with the Android programming.

When I want to add tabs on my application, I create a code using my tabs and Intent related to these tabs.

Now, I would get the instance of the activity created by my tab. (To retrieve a field of Public tab for example 2 and concatenate with a public field of the 3. All in my activity that launched the sight TabHost)

How to do this without using the Static?

Thank you in advance,
Julien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using differents activities for each tab?

If yes, and considering the field as a string, in the example 2:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourThirdActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Field2", field2.toString());
```

In the example 3:

```
    intent = getIntent();
    Field2 = intent.getStringExtra("Field2");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,

In fact the problem is not this one.

The activity that will create my Intent to my tab, must retrieve fields (actually this is the string, the URI, the Rate (with stars)) that are present in my tabs (thus, in the activity created by my tabs).

I realized that I could pass something from my "TabMain" to my "Tab1", Tab2 "," Tab3 ", but I would do the reverse, retrieve data from" Tab1 ", Tab2", "Tab3 "since my" TabMain "!

I do not know if I'm clear, over the language barrier does not play in my favor!

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best solution I think, but it work :

```
public class Tab2 extends Activity {

static Tab2 Instance;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Instance = this;
{...}
```

```
public class TabMain extends TabActivity {


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
{... Create and launch all Intent Tab ...}
String value = Tab2.Instance.MyMethodReturnSomeThing();
{...}
```

For the moment, it's my solution.
If you have better think about that :/